# How to hide some text on TRAC wiki-page from anonymous user?

Tags: wiki, trac

I have a public TRAC installation, but O don't wont to show some links on
wiki-pages (except on the main) for non-logged-in (anonymous) uses.

Can I hide some text for non-logged users, using WikiFormatting tricks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some macros or plugins from the [Trac Hacks](http://trac-hacks.org/) site. Try out:

- [Protected Macro](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ProtectedMacro)
- [Access Macro](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccessMacro)